# Reducing nested if statements

Tags: java

I have a set of rules as follows:

**Product One:**

- If either part is acceptable, update both parts

**Product Two:**

- If either part is acceptable, and one age is > 55, update both parts
- If either part is acceptable, and neither age is > 55, then update whichever part needs updating (or both)

I know it's not the *most* nested `if` statements you'll see, but it feels like I'm repeating code unnecessary and there should be a simpler version of what I've attempted.

**The Code:**

```
 if (this.isAcceptablePartOne || this.isAcceptablePartTwo) {
    if (this.productName.equals(PRODUCT_ONE)) {
        updatePartOne();
        updatePartTwo();
    }
    if (this.productName.equals(PRODUCT_TWO)) {
        if (Math.max(this.ageLifeOne, this.ageLifeTwo) > 55) {
            updatePartOne();
            updatePartTwo();
        } else {
            if (this.isAcceptablePartOne) {
                updatePartOne();
            }
            if (this.isAcceptablePartTwo) {
                updatePartTwo();
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly. Also, there isn't enough context to review the code.

Comment: @Zeta fair enough on the title. But I'm not sure how I could provide more information regarding what I was trying to do with the code. Depending on specific scenarios, I need to update part one, part two or both.

Comment: If it is possible could you show us your `Product`-class. I think it could be too big and should be dismembered into several small ones..

Comment: Please show more context. What method does this code appear in? What class is `this`? I suspect that you may be able to improve the code further with a better design altogether.

Answer (score 2):

### From the requirements

> I have a set of rules as follows:
>
> **Product One:**
>
> If either part is acceptable, update both parts
>
> **Product Two:**
>
> If either part is acceptable, and one age is > 55, update both parts
>
> If either part is acceptable, and neither age is > 55, then update
>   whichever part needs updating (or both)

Follows the next, almost literal, straightforward implementation:

### Straightforward implementation

So, you could implement this using two `Checker`s, a `Product1Checker` and a `Product2Checker`.

```
if (this.productName.equals(PRODUCT_ONE))
{
    new Product1Checker().check(this);
}
else if (this.productName.equals(PRODUCT_TWO))
{
    new Product2Checker().check(this);
}
```

Like this:

```
class Product1Checker 
{

    public check (Product product)
    {
         if (product.isAcceptablePartOne || product.isAcceptablePartTwo) 
         {
               product.updatePartOne();
               product.updatePartTwo();
         }
    }
}
```

### Alternative approach

You could have the `Checkers` implement a `ProductChecker` interface. Also, each `ProductChecker` can have a `boolean` method indicating if this checker applies to a product. Then you can just add all the checkers to a `Set`, check if they are applicable, and if so, run them on the product

```
interface ProductChecker
{
    boolean check     (Product p);
    boolean appliesTo (Product p);
}

Set<ProductChecker> checkers = new HashSet<ProductChecker>();
checkers.add(new Product1Checker());
checkers.add(new Product2Checker());

for (ProductChecker checker: checkers)
{
      if (checker.appliesTo(this))
      {
          checker.check(this));
      }
}
```